# Associated production mode of Higgs production at Tevatron

Tags: higgs, tevatron

We know that at LHC the dominant mode of Higgs Production is Gluon Gluon Fusion, followed by Vector Boson Fusion, and then by Associated production.

Although Tevatron did not show any significance above 2$\sigma$ for a Higgs discovery, my professor mentioned that the best mode of Higgs production is associated production at Tevatron. Why is it the best mode at Tevatron even though GGF has significantly higher NNNLO crossection?